# Tier Pricing of simple product not working with bundle

Tags: product, bundled-product, products-management, tierprice

Bundle items don't seem to listen to the simple product tier pricings. Is it possible to set up a product to sell in this way at all with a fixed service charge and tier pricing?

I have the following tier pricing of a simple product

```
Price = £2 
10+ = £1
20+ = £0.75
```

Now I am wanting to sell this product as part of a bundle, with a fixed set up cost for the bundle of £10.

How is this possible to set up a product so the £10 is a fixed cost, but that magento also follows the tier pricing of the simple product in the bundle (which it does not seem to be doing)

Examples

Customer purchases 1 item = £12

Customer purchases 10 items = £20

Customer purchases 20 items = £25

Thanks for the help. I am figuring i am either missing something obvious, or this needs some sort of hack?

Comment: How does the display for this need to be broken out?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in `Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Price::getSelectionFinalTotalPrice()`:

```
if ($bundleProduct->getPriceType() == self::PRICE_TYPE_DYNAMIC) {
    $price = $selectionProduct->getFinalPrice($takeTierPrice ? $selectionQty : 1);
}
```

Here the configured selection quantity `$selectionQty` is used for tier price calculation but the quantity of the bundle itself is ignored. By the way, the parameter of `getFinalPrice()` is only used for tier price calculation, the method always returns a unit price.

A fix would look like this:

```
if ($bundleProduct->getPriceType() == self::PRICE_TYPE_DYNAMIC) {
    $price = $selectionProduct->getFinalPrice($takeTierPrice ? $selectionQty * max(1, $bundleQty) : 1);
}
```

I.e. if the quantity of the bundle $bundleQty is known, it will be multiplied.

To save the price correctly not only in the bundle but also in the selection itself, we have to trigger a recalculation of their final price as well because at least in some cases it is already calculcated (wrong) at this point. To achieve this, I added the following lines at the beginning of the method:

```
if ($takeTierPrice) {
    $selectionProduct->setFinalPrice(null);
}
```

**Attention:** You should not change core files directly, always use class rewrites if possible or at least copy the patched file below `app/code/local/Mage`.

I wrote a little extension that fixes this together with another bundle tier pricing bug, you can get it from https://github.com/sgh-it/bundletierprices

**Further reading:** http://www.schmengler-se.de/en/2014/10/magento-buendelprodukte-staffelpreise-der-einfachen-produkte-nutzen/

Answer (score 1):

This needs some sort of hack or module. This is not possible out-of-the-box.

Comment: Any Suggestions?

Comment: No. I never used the tier prices til now. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Think this might help you out -

http://www.webshopapps.com/uk/appshop/tiered-pricing-across-multiple-products.html

Used it myself a while ago to solve a similar situation.

Comment: This extension seems to solve an entirely different problem: tier prices across products, similar to shopping cart price rules.

Comment: Link doesnt work anymore.